# How to solve Error: [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "React/Core"

Tags: npm, cocoa, cocoapods, apple-m1

I am working with an M1 Chip, my colleagues don't. The first error I got is : [image: I tried pod repo update and pod install --repo-update. Both not working]

Then I also deleted the Pod, Podfile and node_modules.

I tried following solutions:
[image]
[image]

When it didn't worked I tried to uninstall with:
[image]

and tried both options, first Y and the second time I did 'N'.

I assume my I accidentally changed/messed up my Path..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is simple ,
Go to ./node-module/react-native-fetch-blob/react-native-fetch-blob.podspec. and Change
`s.dependency 'React/Core'`
to `s.dependency 'React-Core'`